# How to include Flashvars in an App Engine response?

Tags: flash, google-app-engine, flashvars

I have a Flash movie I'm trying to return in an App Engine handler, but I'd like to dynamically embed Flashvars before returning the .swf file.

Basically trying to get it so a request for:

http://app.appspot.com/someurixyz

returns the equivalent of:

http://app.appspot.com/xyz.swf?myvar=something

Answer (score 1):

Guess I should have thought about this a little more before posting..

Was able to accomplish this by reading in the url that the SWF file was loaded from:

In AS3:

```
url = this.root.loader.loaderInfo.url;
```